# NSDate assign problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I would like to assign a date from one view controller to another

```
-(void) setCurrentDate:(NSDate newDate){
    self.currentDate = newDate;
    [self updateView];
}
```

While debugging I see the `currentDate` value out of scope and the application crashes with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the pointer to date. Something like this:

```
-(void) setCurrentDate:(NSDate* newDate){
    [self.currentDate release];
    self.currentDate = newDate;
    [self.currentDate retain];
    [self updateView];
}
```

Of course, your `currentDate` class variable should also be a NSDate pointer. It will be even better if you use a property instead of a custom made setter.

Comment: That would recursively call the setter.

Comment: Thanks, this correct, I am already using a property with synthize and release as appropiate.

Comment: @Mohammed: Have you tested this before accepting? This will result in `-setCurrentDate:` being called recursively and finally crash with an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` or similar.

Comment: Agreed - with self.currentDate you are calling the setter for currentDate, which is overridden by the method here, setCurrentDate:. It is infinite recursion.

Answer (score 2):

Besides that your setter should take `NSDate` by pointer (all class-type instances are passed by pointer in Objective-C), you are recursively calling the setter:
`self.currentDate = foo` results in `[self setCurrentDate:foo]` being called.

Correctly it should look e.g. like this (assuming a `nonatomic, retain` property):

```
- (void)setCurrentDate:(NSDate *)newDate {
    if (currentDate != newDate) {
        [currentDate release];
        [newDate retain];
        currentDate = newDate;
        [self updateView];
    }
}
```

Alternatively name that method different from the setter so you can use the synthesized setter:

```
- (void)updateDate:(NSDate *)newDate {
    self.currentDate = newDate;
    [self updateView];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, you need to retain newDate or copy it, if it's possible.

What I mean:

1. You create newDate
2. You call setCurrentDate
3. You release newDate
4. [self updateView] try to use it and fails because it is already released.

You also can try NSZombieEnabled to catch this kind of bugs.

Comment: the currentDate member is created in the viewDidLoad event and retained
    currentDate = [[[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0] retain];

it is also synthized

I am totally fed up because everything looks correct.

Answer (score 0):

In your method name, you use (NSDate date). You forgot to include the "*", which makes it a pointer. The correct code should be

```
-(void) setCurrentDate:(NSDate *newDate){ // Notice the star after NSDate

    self.currentDate = newDate;
    [self updateView];

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot it in the question, but it is correct in the code

Comment: That would also recursively call the setter.